# What does the 'extern' keyword does that makes the following code legal?

Tags: c++, c, global-variables, extern

Why does the following code compile? 
when is the 'num' variable getting its value?

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int num;

void main()
{
    printf("%d", num); //prints 3
}

int num = 3;
```

Example: [Live Code](http://codepad.org/IjL0jUFB)

Comment: If I remove `extern`, what will be the issue?

Comment: Have you ever used `extern` to use a variable in multiple files? This works the same, but in one file.

Comment: @SouravGhosh the code will not compile

Comment: @Nemmy is it? I'm interested. :)

Comment: @Nemmy `nt num`... really?

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry my bad by mistake

Comment: @SouravGhosh that's what happens https://ideone.com/rt8Art

Comment: @Nemmy Choose one language. C is different than C++. Read about tentative definition...

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
 extern int num;
```

is called a *declaration*. OTOH,

```
int num = 3;
```

is the definition with explicit initialization. This statement *sets* the value. This value is decided at the compile time and set just before `main()` starts it's execution.

That said, `void main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least to conform to the standard.

Comment: OP is asking when. The answer is "just before `main` runs".

Comment: Yes I know the difference between declaration & definition but the point here is that 'num' gets declared after main is called; in fact if you remove the extern keyword it will not compile!

Comment: Here, it is similar to a function prototype. The `extern` made it available, even though its value (implementation) was defined later. The compiler ensured its value is set before `main` is run, even though it is defined after in the source file.

Answer (score 2):

It works because you've declared `num` so it can be named in the function's code, and because you've *defined* it at namespace scope so that it's initialised at static-initialisation time, which is just before `main` is executed.

In that sense, your program as currently written is largely indistinguishable from the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num = 3;

void main()
{
    printf("%d", num); //prints 3
}
```

"Where" you initialise the variable isn't particularly relevant, as long as that occurs in time before you try to use it.

*By the way, you must make `main` return `int`, not `void`.*

Answer (score 1):

`extern` marks a declaration of a variable that's defined later. The definition, the `int num = 3;` part, is what actually allocates the memory for the variable and sets it's value (it also doubles as a declaration). C/C++ are declare-before-use, if you didn't do that `extern int num;` then `num` wouldn't be declared at the point you use it. You could also of course drop the `extern` line and move the definition of `num` up to above `main()`.

There's two things that come into play here. During compile, `num` has to be declared at a point in the source file before any use. As for when it gets it's value assigned, that comes during program loading. All variables at file scope (outside any functions) like `num` have their memory allocated and their values if any initialized before `main()` is called. If they aren't given a value in their definition they may contain anything, so don't make any assumptions about the value of uninitialized variables. You also can't make any assumptions about the order they're initialized in, so don't refer to other file-scope variables when initializing a variable like this.

Answer (score 0):

`extern` is used with the declaration. It tells the compiler that the thing will be defined elsewhere. It's useful when you have multiple files using the same variable or function. You would put an `extern` declaration in a header file, and define the shared variable/function in a source file.

If you remove `extern` from your code you will be defining `num` twice, which isn't allowed. To get rid of the `extern` declaration, just put your `int num = 3;` at the top of your file.